# Is it possible to override the progress bar of TensorFlow's keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In the last days, I have been observing a weird behavior in the printed loss in the progress bar. It turned out that the weird behaviour was due to the fact that [the default progress bar of keras displays a *moving average* of the losses](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L614) (rather than the actual losses at every epoch).

So, is it possible to override the progress bar of TensorFlow's keras? I don't think so.

There's the class [`tf.keras.utils.Progbar`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Progbar) that contains the parameter `stateful_metrics`, which is probably what I need, but [`fit`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) doesn't seem to provide an option to override the progress bar or to change the behaviour from moving average to actual loss of the epoch/step. What alternative do you suggest? Feel free to write an answer below with some reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want should be done through `tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger`. Theoretically it should work as outlined in the following example, however, there is currently an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38765) with `tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255, x_test / 255

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10)
])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])
progbar_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger(stateful_metrics="accuracy")
model.fit(x_train, y_train, callbacks=[progbar_callback])
```